# OAuth Mechanism,User and password flow

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I am using user pasword login authentication mechanism.I am doing this between two salesforce org.I have done the initial setup and I will be using Rest Api's.

I can see instance and  access token in the response .However ,I am not able to retrieve access token and Instance Url from the resposne.Can somebody please help me in accomplising that?I have Json format.

```
Static void login()
{

String ClientId='3MVG9xOCXq4ID1uGdZWMIUrMaRqoXtucMSraEOK1FxY.LQ78FdWYfStd7VGKBPCcS4OdjXHCmQ36ULHEzowxf';
String ClientSecret='5999022735349169870'; 
String username='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
String password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');
req.setBody('grant_type=password' +
            '&client_id=' + clientId +
            '&client_secret=' + clientSecret +
            '&username=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(username, 'UTF-8') +
            '&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(password, 'UTF-8'));


        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        System.debug('BODY: '+res.getBody());
        System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());
        //jsonObjectj=new JsonObject(res.getBody());


        //String accessToken = var.getValue('access_token').str;
        //System.debug('The value in teh access token is'+accessToken);
        //String instanceUrl = var.getValue('instance_url').str;
        //System.debug('instance URL'+instanceURL);


//        return new JSONObject(res.getBody());

    }

}
```

Comment: you might also take a look at http://cropredysfdc.com/2013/12/06/salesforce-to-salesforce-using-rest-part-i/ for other bits that might help you (@metadaddy's response is correct.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [System JSON methods](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_class_System_Json.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fapex_class_System_Json.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp). I would go with `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` as you don't need to create an Apex helper class, and you only need a couple of fields:

```
Map<String, Object> oauth = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
String accessToken = (String)oauth.get('access_token');
String instanceUrl = (String)oauth.get('instance_url');
```